# Why does ruby script stop when trying to start unicorn_rails as daemon?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bash, unicorn

I'm trying to start unicorn_rails in a ruby script, and after executing many commands in the script, when the script gets to the following line

```
 %x[bash -ic "bash <(. ~/.bashrc); cd /home/www-data/rails_app;   bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 8000 -E production -c /home/www-data/rails_app/config/unicorn.rb  -D"]
```

the script stops, generating the following output

```
[1]+  Stopped                 ./setup_rails.rb
```

and returns to the Linux prompt.  If I type "fg", the script finishes running, the line where the script had stopped gets executed and unicorn gets started as a daemon.

If I run the line in a separate script, the script completes without stopping.

**UPDATE_1 -**

I source .bashrc because earlier in the script I install rvm and to get it to run with the correct environment I have the following:

```
 %x[echo "[[ -s \"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\" ]] && source \"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\""  >> .bashrc]
 %x[bash -ic "bash <(. ~/.bashrc); rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290; rvm 1.9.2-p290 --default;"]
```

So if I want to run correct version of rvm, ruby and bundle I need to source .bashrc

**end UPDATE_1**

Does anyone have any idea what could cause a ruby script to halt as if control-Z was pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's stopping, but my general rule of thumb is to never source my .bashrc in a script -- that might be the source of your problem right there, but I can't be sure without seeing what's in it. You should be able to change your script to something like:

```
$ vi setup_rails.sh

#!/usr/bin/bash

# EDIT from comments below
#  expanding from a one liner to a better script...

$RVM_PATH=$HOME/.rvm/scripts

# install 1.9.2-p290 unless it's installed
$RVM_PATH/rvm info 1.9.2-p290 2&>1 >/dev/null || $RVM_SH install 1.9.2-p290 

# run startup command inside rvm shell
$RVM_PATH/rvm-shell 1.9.2-p290 -c "cd /home/www-data/rails_app && bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 8000 -E production -c /home/www-data/rails_app/config/unicorn.rb  -D"
```

This should give you the same result.

Comment: #Josh - I added an UPDATE 1 that explains why I am sourcing .bashrc.

Comment: I see... rvm... I very much avoid using rvm in production (or just about any) environments. But if that's what you're shooting for, there's a few options. (seems enter save comments, continuing) First, checkout `rvm-exec`, I've never gotten it to work properly, but it's suppose to work sort of like `bundle exec` AFAIK. I have, in the past, simple called ruby with the full path to the rvm install. Ugly, but it should work. I'm trying to find an example, but it's been a while since using it and they seemed to have disappeared.

Comment: Okay, from a little searching you should be able to simply do `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290 2>/dev/null; $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell ruby-1.9.2-p290 -c "cd /home/www-data/rails_app && bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 8000 -E production -c /home/www-data/rails_app/config/unicorn.rb  -D
"` This is untested, it or something very close to it *should* work.

Comment: Also, to your original question `bash <(. ~/.bashrc);` most likely source `.bashrc` in to a new bash session, not the one you're loading. I ran a quick test locally and that's what I'm seeing.

Comment: I played around with it a bit and something like the following might work: `$(cat ~/.bashrc); bash -ic "...your command..."`.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I finally was able to test this.  I wasn't able to get your last suggestion to work, the one starting with $(cat ~/.bashrc);  But your third comment worked with $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell ruby-1.9.2-p290 -c "cd /home/www-data/rails_app && bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 8000 -E production -c /home/www-data/rails_app/config/unicorn.rb -D ".  Thanks again for your help!!!